# Azure blob storage REST API: Why "Get Blob Properties" and "Get Blob" requests are the same?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Looking at the MSDN documentation for Get Blob and Get Blob Properties. Both requests are looking the same

**"https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob"**

Get Properties: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179440.aspx

Get Blob Properties:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179394.aspx

I must be missing a point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HTTP method of "Get Blob" is GET, but the HTTP method of "Get Blob Properties" is HEAD.

The response of "Get Blob" is blob properties (in response headers) and blob content (in response body), but the response of "Get Blob Properties" only contains blob properties in headers.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Get Blob Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179394.aspx) page,

> It does not return the content of the blob.

I believe that's the difference between these two

Comment: This does not answer the question. I think the OP understand the difference between both responses. What he doesn't get is why the request are the same.

Comment: Get Blob uses HTTP "GET"
Get Blob Properties uses HTTP "HEAD"

GET
The GET method requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only retrieve data.

HEAD
The HEAD method asks for a response identical to that of a GET request, but without the response body.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods